# TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor initial value

Tags: android, android-sensors, euler-angles

I have a screen on my app that simulate the rotation of device's angle.
Each time I enter this screen, I register to listen the TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor and receive the value from it and calculate the euler angles.
But I see that no matter where the device are, the yaw angle that I calculate from this sensor's initial value is the same (on my device, it's always -11 and other is -90).
So what cause this problem and how to fix it?

Here is my calculation's code:

```
private fun calculateAngle(eventValues: FloatArray) {
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, eventValues)
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X,    SensorManager.AXIS_Y, outR)
            SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, orientationAngles)
        _yaw = Math.toDegrees(orientationAngles[0].toDouble()).toFloat()
```